# Implement BottomSheetScaffold or ModalBottomSheetLayout as independent component without screen content

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I've been trying to implement a generic bottom sheet component in the app which can be open on top of any fragment or activity, In this way I can migrate my existing [Common BottomSheetDialogFragment Component](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet/BottomSheetDialogFragment) to compose using [ModalBottomSheetLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#modalbottomsheetlayout)

In my eyes i see this as a limitation where we can't create a compose bottom sheet as a separate screen/component on top of another screen which is bit less scalable and can't reuse existing stuff.

example:

```
    ModalBottomSheetLayout(
    sheetContent = {
        // Bottom Sheet content
    }
) {
    // "Here the Screen content is not interoperable with XML and reusable"
}
```

can anyone suggest any workaround or a possible solution?
thanks in advance.

Comment: What makes you say that it is not interoperable in that particular scope?

Comment: I meant we always have to have compose-based UI to set as screen content so no option to use XML layouts, both content are coupled with each other, so i can't reuse the bottom sheet content anywhere else in the project

Comment: You can use the interoperability API, such as the `AndroidView()` to use XML-defined traditional views in a Composable scope.

Comment: the only solution I can think of is adding a compose view in BottomSheetDialogFragment's XML which is still a traditional approach.

Comment: Fragments and multiple activities are now discouraged. Just make a single activity, and implement Compose Navigation to create multiple screens.

Comment: So you are currently coding in the view system or Compose? because I recommended using AndroidView, while you interpreted a ComposeView. This means you're familiar with the interoperability APIs, but are in a different paradigmn.

Comment: yes, that's true, the only pressing thing is the existing component is used widely, so I'm looking for something which can act as an alternative in Compose, but thanks I'll look into other way with AndroidView() as well.